# popup window not work in php echo

Tags: php, popup

it can appear a simple question but i have searched untill writing here but no answer. i have a php code and i what to start a pop up window after echo :

> ```
>           echo "<A HREF='map2.php' onClick='return popup(this,'notes')'>WHATEVER</A>";
> ```

```
   in the head section i have :
```

> ```
>        <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
>                 <!--
>               function popup(mylink, windowname)
>                {
>                 if (! window.focus)return true;
>               var href;
>                if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
>              href=mylink;
>                else
>                href=mylink.href;
>              window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=235,scrollbars=yes');
>                return false;
>             }
> ```

at the end is the ending script tag but i dont succide in adding it.

anyway.the pop up doesn work. the link opens in the same page.

i also tried :

> ```
>       <a href="map2.php" onclick="window.open('map2.php','popup','width=600,height=700,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=50,top=0');  return false">About</a>
> ```

and it doesnt work. it opens in the same page. The funny thing is that all these 2 solutions worked in html page, but when used between php , after "echo" , it doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line you posted (the php echo), it seems to me you have a problem with ' in side '

Try the following:

```
echo "<A HREF='map2.php' onClick=\"return popup(this,'notes')\">WHATEVER</A>";
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here your [quoting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

When outputting HTML I recommend using single quotes with `echo` as it allows you to use the *proper* double quotes for the HTML tags.

```
echo '<a href="map2.php" onClick="return popup(this, \'notes\');">Whatever</a>';
```

The problem with your original code was that you had quotes within quotes that were breaking the syntax. Read the link I posted to see how to handle quotes properly with PHP.

Comment: i changed the quotes. the same effect